# In Drush what is the difference between ard and arb?

Tags: drush

In Drush what is the difference between ard and arb commands? When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're actually aliases of one another, so you can use either.

If you type `drush help arb` you'll see at the bottom:

```
Aliases: ard, archive-backup, arb
```

And for posterity, `drush help ard`:

```
Aliases: ard, archive-backup, arb
```